# Parsing a wiki-styled web page, XPath error

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, wiki

I am new to XPath, and I totally fail to parse a simple wiki-styled web page with lxml.

I have a following expression:

```
"".join(tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p//text()'))
```

It works fine, but I need to exclude children whose class is "reference" and get a lxml.etree.XPathEvalError with a following expression:

```
"".join(tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p//*[not(@class="reference")].text()'))
```

What is the right XPath expression? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the error occured because of `.text()` instead of `/text()`.

If you want include also text of `p` elements then you have to use the `descendant-or-self` [XPath axis](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp):

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p/descendant-or-self::*[not(@class="reference")]/text()
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation to your code? This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I understood it yesterday, and the final XPath expression is  `//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p/descendant-or-self::*[not(ancestor::sup)]/text()`.